# Is there a way to instruct Visual Studio Code to skip git commit hooks (i.e., to supply the -n argument)?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to install a pre-commit hook, but also to be able to commit under certain circumstances (e.g., WIP) even when the hook fails. I can do this easily from the command line, using `git commit --no-verify` (`git commit -n`). But I can't find anything that allows me to affect the commit in VSCode other than the text field for the commit message.

Am I missing it, or is it not there?

Comment: Update: the `git commit -n` / `--no-verify`will be there soon (Sept. 2020, VSCode 1.50). See my [updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403776/6309).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a way to instruct Visual Studio Code to skip `git commit` hooks (i.e., to supply the `-n` argument)?

Update Sept 2020: there is, with VSCode 1.50 (Sept 2020), which adds the missing option for `git commit` in VSCode.

See [PR 106335](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/106335): Adds commands for `--no-verify` commit variants

> This PR adds `*NoVerify` command variants for creating commits while skipping pre-commit and commit-msg hooks.
>
> The commands are only displayed if the `git.allowNoVerifyCommit` option is set to true.
> This type of commits requires additional confirmation (like `git.pushForce` does), which can be bypassed by disabling the `git.confirmNoVerifyCommit` option.

See the (now released) [VSCode 1.50 "Git: Commit --no-verify commands"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_50#_git-commit-noverify-commands)

> Git commit commands with the `--no-verify` flag are now available after enabling the `git.allowNoVerifyCommit` setting.
>
> [image: git --no-verify in command palette -- https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_50/git-no-verify.png]

---

Original answer Dec. 2019: From VSCode alone:

- there is no such option in [`extensions/git/src/git.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/git/src/git.ts) (but its could be amended by a patch, if a contributor might chose to)

From a VSCode extension, like [GitLens](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens)

- there is no such option even in its issues: this has not been requested before.

Comment: How did you get that build? I'm running 1.49.1 on OSX, and I just checked for updates manually and didn't get a new version.

Comment: @LucioMollinedo Since  it is for 1.50, I am not surprise you don't see it with 1.49.x. You would need to test with the VSCode Insider edition: https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

Comment: Insider edition. I see. I don't use that build. Thanks!

Comment: Did anyone notice the typo 'No Nerify'? :D I'd rather wait till this gets promoted to the stable build.

Comment: @ΕГИІИО This is released already. I have updated my answer and the picture. There is no more typo on "No Verify".

Comment: @VonC That's strange. I seem to be running 1.51.1 but I don't see the no verify commands :|

Comment: @VonC Stupid me, I've taken them off settings. All good! Cheers!

Comment: @ΕГИІИО I was about to comment: `git.allowNoVerifyCommit` must be set to true, indeed.

Answer (score 19):

### Enable No Verify Commits

Go into VSCode settings and enable: `git.allowNoVerifyCommit`

```json
"git.allowNoVerifyCommit": true
```

### Profit

#### Source Control Panel

Now you can use the: **Commit (No Verify)** option through the Source Control panel.

[image: Git commit no verify through source control panel.]

#### Command Palette

Or you can use it through the Command Palette.

[image: Git commit no verify through command palette.]